# Keeping track of service changes on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, services, debug

Applications often add new services to Windows, some of which start automatically even though they are unnecessary and sometimes interfere with other programs for no good reason.

Is there any way to track what's happening in the list of services? For example some program that would take a snapshot of the service list at regular intervals and show me what's been changed recently? That way if something breaks in my system I know where to look.

Any idea if something like this exist?

(Specifically it's for Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up creating a small PHP script under Bash for Windows to do the job. It calls `wmic` to get the list of services, then saves this in a text file that's versioned using git. It's called once a day in cron.

Then I can use something like `tig` to view the changes over time.

[image]

Here's the script if someone's interested in doing something similar (it's bit hacky but it works):

```php
<?php

$wmicPath = '/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem/WMIC.exe';

$logDir = $_SERVER['HOME'] . '/var/log/win_services_mon';
@mkdir($logDir, 0755, true);
chdir($logDir);

$logFile = $logDir . '/services.log';

if (!file_exists($logDir . '/.git')) {
    exec('git init');
}

exec($wmicPath . ' service get name,caption,startmode > ' . $logFile);
$content = file_get_contents($logFile);
if (strpos($content, 'ÿþ') === 0) {
    $content = substr($content, 2); // Remove BOM
}
$content = str_replace("\0", '', $content); // Convert two bytes per character to one (definitely the wrong way to do this, but can't get iconv to work)
file_put_contents($logFile, $content);

exec('git add .');
exec('git commit -m "' . date('Ymd-His') . '"');
```

Answer (score 0):

*Nice one, but over-complex from requirements point of view.*

A way, valid without anything 3rd-party installed, is to use a batch file.

Just run `wmic service get name,caption,startmode` with output parameter as filename+currentdate/time. (i.e >> out20170509.log, next day output to out20170510.log).

That will create the files.

Then, you can task schedule another bat file with FC (file compare between the files) that itself can output to a cmd (with pause or delay) or to another text file you can check later.